# I got an error during activity start

Tags: android

```
07-26 13:32:38.705: ERROR/Zygote(32): setreuid() failed. errno: 2
07-26 13:32:46.206: ERROR/Zygote(32): setreuid() failed. errno: 17
07-26 13:32:47.526: ERROR/BatteryService(58): usbOnlinePath not found
07-26 13:32:47.526: ERROR/BatteryService(58): batteryVoltagePath not found
07-26 13:32:47.526: ERROR/BatteryService(58): batteryTemperaturePath not found
07-26 13:32:47.556: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(58): Couldn't open /sys/power/wait_for_fb_sleep or /sys/power/wait_for_fb_wake
07-26 13:32:54.275: ERROR/EventHub(58): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse0, Not a typewriter
07-26 13:32:54.285: ERROR/EventHub(58): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mice, Not a typewriter
07-26 13:32:54.496: ERROR/System(58): Failure starting core service
07-26 13:32:54.496: ERROR/System(58): java.lang.SecurityException
07-26 13:32:54.496: ERROR/System(58):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
07-26 13:32:54.496: ERROR/System(58):     at android.os.ServiceManagerProxy.addService(ServiceManagerNative.java:146)
07-26 13:32:54.496: ERROR/System(58):     at android.os.ServiceManager.addService(ServiceManager.java:72)
07-26 13:32:54.496: ERROR/System(58):     at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:184)
07-26 13:32:55.756: ERROR/SoundPool(58): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-26 13:32:55.765: ERROR/SoundPool(58): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
07-26 13:32:55.775: ERROR/SoundPool(58): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
07-26 13:32:55.795: ERROR/SoundPool(58): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
07-26 13:32:55.804: ERROR/SoundPool(58): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
07-26 13:32:59.184: ERROR/ThrottleService(58): Could not open GPS configuration file /etc/gps.conf
07-26 13:33:00.706: ERROR/logwrapper(148): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
07-26 13:33:00.764: ERROR/logwrapper(149): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
07-26 13:33:00.815: ERROR/logwrapper(150): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
07-26 13:33:12.188: ERROR/HierarchicalStateMachine(58): TetherMaster - unhandledMessage: msg.what=3
07-26 13:34:04.617: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-26 13:34:04.617: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dataApplication/com.dataApplication.Edit}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
07-26 13:34:04.617: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
07-26 13:34:04.617: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
07-26 13:34:04.617: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
07-26 13:34:04.617: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
07-26 13:34:04.617: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-26 13:34:04.617: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-26 13:34:04.617: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-26 13:34:04.617: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-26 13:34:04.617: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-26 13:34:04.617: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-26 13:34:04.617: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-26 13:34:04.617: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-26 13:34:04.617: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
07-26 13:34:04.617: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:245)
07-26 13:34:04.617: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:201)
07-26 13:34:04.617: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
07-26 13:34:04.617: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at com.dataApplication.Edit.onCreate(Edit.java:32)
07-26 13:34:04.617: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-26 13:34:04.617: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
07-26 13:34:04.617: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 2):

> java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Make sure your view file has a `ListView` element, with `android:id="@android:id/list"`.
This is how the `ListActivity` knows where to display the data you're adding.

Answer (score 1):

From http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html

> ListActivity has a default layout that consists of a single, full-screen list in the center of the screen. However, if you desire, you can customize the screen layout by setting your own view layout with setContentView() in onCreate(). To do this, your own view MUST contain a ListView object with the id "@android:id/list" (or list if it's in code)

Check if you have "@android:id/list" in your xml ?